# CNN model, How does dense layer in CNN divide into two streams using keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am working on the CNN model. In the given CNN model I can not handle how to divide the 4th layer into two streams and get output.[image]

I also built a model in Keras.

```
def _build_model(self):
    model = Sequential()
   
    model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), strides=4, padding='same', input_shape=self.state_size))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
   
    model.add(Conv2D(2, (2, 2), strides=4, padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
   
    model.add(Flatten())        
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='relu'))
 
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam())
    return model
```

How to handle it? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you will need to use the "functional interface", which allows more general graphs than the "straight line graphs" you get using "Sequential".

Comment: @MarkLavin thanks for the reply. Can you give me some reference or tutorials, how to use the "functional interface"?

Comment: There are some good Coursera courses about this, including one from Imperial College London.   The functional API is described in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: If I am not wrong, I need to make a custom dense layer for 4th layer in my CNN model, like this class CustomDense(layers.Layer): kindly correct me if there is a mistake.

Comment: "Custom layer" is somewhat different from the capability that the functional interface gives; I'd call the latter "Custom flow", since, in this case, it allows you to pass the output of "Dense3" into the two layers of "Dense4", which operate independently.   There is also the question of where the two branches of "Dense4" need to be combined in the model, either by a layer that takes two inputs (e.g., "plus") or a "concatenate" layer.

Comment: @MarkLavin, how do I contact you for further discussion?

Comment: I'm happy to continue the discussion here.

Comment: @MarkLavin, I want that you check my model code.

Comment: Please post the code as an edit on the original question.

Comment: @zoraizali you could probably use the `Lambda` layer plus `tf.slice` to split the output of Dense3 ReLU. But as Mark said, you do need to use the functional API for that.